# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Why can´t load PHP a extenal SOAP entity?
The Error:
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

My fist idea: Can php accept a extenal https document?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://soatest.paysafecard.com/psc/services/PscService?wsdl' :
failed to load external entity "https://soatest.paysafecard.com/psc/services/PscService?wsdl" in /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/class.php:791
    Stack trace: 
     #0 /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/class.php(791): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://soatest...')
     #1 /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/class.php(25): SOPGClassicMerchantClient->clientConnect() 
     #2 /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/payment.php(56): SOPGClassicMerchantClient->__construct(true, 'de', true, 'test') 
     #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/class.php on line 791
```

PHP Info

```
soap

Soap Client enabled
Soap Server enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400

openssl

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
```

Comment: Calling the WSDL's URL in my browser returns 403 Forbidden. This is the reason for your error I guess.

Comment: @R3N3PDE Hi, did you find a solution to this? The url still returns 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and fixed it by contacting paysafe integration@paysafecard.com. They actually added my server's Ip address in their white lists.